# Show HTML table side Columns on middle column hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

See http://jsfiddle.net/38QZ6/1/

```
.feelo_table:hover .labels {
     display:table-cell;
}
```

In the above code the expected output is when I hover the middle table column , I need to popup the side columns, as a wing like projection sideways.
I am half way to it. I couldn't align the side columns properly.

Below is the expected output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pumgy.png]

Comment: Isn't the source code available where you got the news feed from?

Comment: This is the PSD document. I need to transform this to CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also implement transitions:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5D9e2/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>HAPPINESS</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>SADNESS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>RESPECT</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>DISRESPECT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>TRUST</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>DISGUST</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>JOY</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>SADNESS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>EMPATHY</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>APATHY</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    border:2px solid white;
    position:relative;
}
.cell:first-child, .cell:last-child {
    background:white;
    width:200px;
}
.cell:first-child div, .cell:last-child div {
    background:#e1e1e1;
    max-width:0;
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:right;
    line-height:30px;
}
.cell:first-child div {
    right:0;
    text-align:left;
}
.table:hover .cell:first-child div, .table:hover .cell:last-child div {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.cell:nth-child(5), .cell:nth-child(5):hover {
    background-color:#C4B782;
}
.cell:nth-child(4):hover {
    background-color:#E5B623;
}
.cell:nth-child(3):hover {
    background-color:#DD6E24;
}
.cell:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color:#C11616;
}
.cell:nth-child(6):hover {
    background-color:#ABC12B;
}
.cell:nth-child(7):hover {
    background-color:#86A31A;
}
.cell:nth-child(8):hover {
    background-color:#638E04;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me to implement this for cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/38QZ6/8/

for the code snippet:

```
.feelo_table{
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:2px;
    font-family: roboto_slabregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#999;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #999;
    border-radius:2px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi remove the 2 px padding on the .feelo_table element

```
.feelo_table{
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:2px;
  font-family: roboto_slabregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#999;
  font-size:14px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  box-shadow:0 0 2px #999;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38QZ6/2/

Comment: Thats not exactly what i needed, Can you help me to align this side labels look exactly like in the picture i uploaded